# Modify "__cxa_allocate_exception" that no malloc is used

Tags: c++, gcc, exception, malloc

I am working in an safe embedded system, and I want to modify the exception handling a bit. `__cxa_allocate_exception` is using `malloc()` to allocate memory for the exception object. `malloc`/`new` is not allowed in safe applications, so I have to rewrite it.

Now my question: Is there a way to avoid malloc in this case?

Some alternatives would be:

- Using a static buffer, which will lead to problems in multitask / multicore applications, so I can not do that.
- Writing on the heap will also cause some trouble because the heap might be full (Out of memory throw wont work).
- Finally, maybe I could allocate (for example) 16kb of the task stack space and every exception object will have a constant size of 1kb. That way, I can handle up to 16 exceptions. My understanding of the stack is sadly to low, to rate it, if it makes any sense or is even possible.

Comment: Are thread-local variables a viable solution?

Comment: Do you really *need* exceptions? On small embedded systems exceptions are usually a bad idea. Not to mention that throwing an exception is usually quite expensive in C++ so should be used only for truly exceptional events.

Comment: Reserving memory up front will *increase* the risk of running out of memory, not reduce it.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @Someprogrammerdude that if malloc() is not considered safe for your embedded application, then you shouldn't use exceptions as well. But if you need them, the best way, IMHO, is to implement a very simple malloc()/free() over a static buffer. You may look around for some already existing implementations. Modifying exception handling support in the compiler libraries can be a bit tricky and definitely is not recommended, as you need to support it for the future versions of the development toolchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at: `gcc-6.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc` (or a later version). A `pool` (memory) class is specified and instantiated as `emergency_pool` in an anonymous namespace. You could tweak the `EMERGENCY` macro values, or replace the implementation entirely - as long as you account for thread-safety in using the pool.

If you have prior knowledge of your call stack depth, you could fix values for the pool buffer that will always be sufficient. Again, you may need sync primitives here for thread-safety.

In the event that this isn't enough, `__cxa_allocate_exception` calls `std::terminate` if allocation fails. Here's where [`std::set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) might provide you with a last chance of salvaging critical info.

---

For thread-safety, use the same `__gnu_cxx::__mutex` object as the pool does, along with the `__gnu_cxx::__scoped_lock` idiom. That way you're not relying on anything `libsupc++` doesn't rely on, like the standard library atomics or `std::mutex`, or `std::lock_guard` - i.e., creating a dependency on `libstdc++`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is perfect for me. I adepted the emergency_pool as an exception_pool. Like you said I adjusted the pool buffer in respect to my stack depth. At the moment I am searching for a good way to guarantee thread safety.

Comment: @xMutzelx - you can use the same scoped locking that the pool does (see update).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answeres where perfect for me.

Answer (score 5):

We released an open source library which implements an memory pool for exception handling: https://github.com/ApexAI/static_exception